# where is the context switching finally happening in the linux kernel source?

Tags: linux, scheduling

In linux, process scheduling occurs after all interrupts (timer interrupt, and other interrupts) or when a process relinquishes CPU(by calling explicit schedule() function). Today I was trying to see where context switching occurs in linux source (kernel version 2.6.23)
(I think I checked this several years ago but I'm not sure now..I was looking at sparc arch then.)
 I looked it up from the main_timer_handler(in arch/x86_64/kernel/time.c), but couldn't find it.

Finally I found it in ./arch/x86_64/kernel/entry.S.

```
    ENTRY(common_interrupt)
        XCPT_FRAME
        interrupt do_IRQ
        /* 0(%rsp): oldrsp-ARGOFFSET */
    ret_from_intr:
        cli
        TRACE_IRQS_OFF
        decl %gs:pda_irqcount
        leaveq
        CFI_DEF_CFA_REGISTER    rsp
        CFI_ADJUST_CFA_OFFSET   -8
    exit_intr:
        GET_THREAD_INFO(%rcx)
        testl $3,CS-ARGOFFSET(%rsp)
        je retint_kernel

...(omit)
        GET_THREAD_INFO(%rcx)
        jmp retint_check

    #ifdef CONFIG_PREEMPT
        /* Returning to kernel space. Check if we need preemption */
        /* rcx:  threadinfo. interrupts off. */
    ENTRY(retint_kernel)
        cmpl $0,threadinfo_preempt_count(%rcx)
        jnz  retint_restore_args
        bt  $TIF_NEED_RESCHED,threadinfo_flags(%rcx)
        jnc  retint_restore_args
        bt   $9,EFLAGS-ARGOFFSET(%rsp)  /* interrupts off? */
        jnc  retint_restore_args
        call preempt_schedule_irq
        jmp exit_intr
    #endif

        CFI_ENDPROC
    END(common_interrupt)
```

At the end of the ISR is a call to preempt_schedule_irq! and the preempt_schedule_irq is defined in kernel/sched.c as below(it calls schedule() in the middle).

```
/*  
 * this is the entry point to schedule() from kernel preemption
 * off of irq context.
 * Note, that this is called and return with irqs disabled. This will
 * protect us against recursive calling from irq. 
 */ 
asmlinkage void __sched preempt_schedule_irq(void)
{   
    struct thread_info *ti = current_thread_info();
#ifdef CONFIG_PREEMPT_BKL
    struct task_struct *task = current;
    int saved_lock_depth;
#endif
    /* Catch callers which need to be fixed */
    BUG_ON(ti->preempt_count || !irqs_disabled());

need_resched:
    add_preempt_count(PREEMPT_ACTIVE);
    /*
     * We keep the big kernel semaphore locked, but we
     * clear ->lock_depth so that schedule() doesnt
     * auto-release the semaphore:
     */
#ifdef CONFIG_PREEMPT_BKL
    saved_lock_depth = task->lock_depth;
    task->lock_depth = -1; 
#endif
    local_irq_enable();
    schedule();
    local_irq_disable();
#ifdef CONFIG_PREEMPT_BKL
    task->lock_depth = saved_lock_depth;
#endif
    sub_preempt_count(PREEMPT_ACTIVE); 

    /* we could miss a preemption opportunity between schedule and now */
    barrier();
    if (unlikely(test_thread_flag(TIF_NEED_RESCHED)))
        goto need_resched; 
}
```

So I found where the scheduling occurs, but my question is,  "where in the source code does the actually context switching happen?". For context switching, the stack, mm settings, registers should be switched and the PC (program counter) should be set to the new task. Where can I find the source code for that? I followed schedule() --> context_switch() --> switch_to(). Below is the context_switch function which calls switch_to() function.(kernel/sched.c)

```
/*
 * context_switch - switch to the new MM and the new
 * thread's register state.
 */
static inline void
context_switch(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *prev,
           struct task_struct *next)
{
    struct mm_struct *mm, *oldmm;

    prepare_task_switch(rq, prev, next);
    mm = next->mm;
    oldmm = prev->active_mm;
    /*
     * For paravirt, this is coupled with an exit in switch_to to
     * combine the page table reload and the switch backend into
     * one hypercall.
     */
    arch_enter_lazy_cpu_mode();

    if (unlikely(!mm)) {
        next->active_mm = oldmm;
        atomic_inc(&oldmm->mm_count);
        enter_lazy_tlb(oldmm, next);
    } else
        switch_mm(oldmm, mm, next);

    if (unlikely(!prev->mm)) {
        prev->active_mm = NULL;
        rq->prev_mm = oldmm;
    }
    /*
     * Since the runqueue lock will be released by the next
     * task (which is an invalid locking op but in the case
     * of the scheduler it's an obvious special-case), so we
     * do an early lockdep release here:
     */
#ifndef __ARCH_WANT_UNLOCKED_CTXSW
    spin_release(&rq->lock.dep_map, 1, _THIS_IP_);
#endif

    /* Here we just switch the register state and the stack. */
    switch_to(prev, next, prev);   // <---- this line

    barrier();
    /*
     * this_rq must be evaluated again because prev may have moved
     * CPUs since it called schedule(), thus the 'rq' on its stack
     * frame will be invalid.
     */
    finish_task_switch(this_rq(), prev);
}
```

The 'switch_to' is an assembly code under include/asm-x86_64/system.h.
my question is, is the processor switched to the new task inside the 'switch_to()' function? Then, are the codes 'barrier(); finish_task_switch(this_rq(), prev);' run at some other time later? By the way, this was in interrupt context, so if to_switch() is just the end of this ISR, who finishes this interrupt? Or, if the finish_task_switch runs, how is CPU occupied by the new task?
I would really appreciate if someone could explain and clarify things to me.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all of the work for a context switch is done by the normal SYSCALL/SYSRET mechanism.  The process pushes its state on the stack of "current" the current running process.  Calling do_sched_yield just changes the value of current, so the return just restores the state of a different task.

Preemption gets trickier, since it doesn't happen at a normal boundary.  The preemption code has to save and restore all of the task state, which is slow.  That's why non-RT kernels avoid doing preemption.  The arch-specific switch_to code is what saves all the prev task state and sets up the next task state so that SYSRET will run the next task correctly.  There are no magic jumps or anything in the code, it is just setting up the hardware for userspace.

Comment: OK, but I still can't understand it. When normal process yields the CPU, it goes into wait queue and gets woken up with all the task states restored. I know it. But like I showed, when the scheduler preempts using timer interrupt(jiffies), it does it with switch_to code. Do you call this switch_to a kind of SYSCALL/SYSRET? I guess so. then my question now is if this switch_to code was entered in the interrupt context(during timer interrupt, doesn't have any task information), how can the code after that switch_to() get entered later? how can CPU reach finish_task_switch(..) function?

Comment: No.  switch_to just manipulates the arch-specific state then returns.  All of the code that calls __schedule (which calls switch_to) is __asmlinkage, meaning it is a syscall and ends with a SYSRET.

Comment: If switch_to just manipulates states and returns, then, when is the PC(program counter) actually changed to that of the next task? I don't think changing register sets includes chaninging program counter register. Am I right? and by SYSCALL/SYSRET, do you mean normal call/return using stack? sorry to ask too many questions, I'll be doing my homework for this.